# Using tabs like database tables

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'd like to use sheets like a database, the big question is how I can keep "foreign-key relationship" when removing or adding new entries in one tab?

An example:

Tab (aka "table") with basic personal information "people":

```
A        |  B         | C                         |  D
First    |  Last      | E-Mail                    |  Relevant
---------------------------------------------------------------
Peter    |  Parker    | peter@parker.net          |  X
Steven   |  Mueller   | steven.mueller@gmail.com  |  
Patricia |  Doe       | pat@pat.com               |  X
```

Based on column D ("Relevant"), I create a list of peoples first names in a second tab "info". Using:

```
=QUERY(people!A:D, "Select A where D='X'")
```

Which results in

```
A        |  B         | C                         |  D
First    |            |                           | 
---------------------------------------------------------
Peter    |
Patricia |
```

I am now adding more information (birth year and city):

```
A        |  B         | C                         |  D
First    |  Year      | City                      | 
---------------------------------------------------------
Peter    |  1990      | New York
Patricia |  1980      | Boston
```

** so far, so good ** now the issue is, how can I preserve this data, if I add more entries to the "people" list? If I add an X for the person "Steven" in the "people" table:

```
A        |  B         | C                         |  D
First    |  Last      | E-Mail                    |  Relevant
---------------------------------------------------------------
Peter    |  Parker    | peter@parker.net          |  X
Steven   |  Mueller   | steven.mueller@gmail.com  |  X
Patricia |  Doe       | pat@pat.com               |  X
```

The table in the second tab will look like this - so Peter will "become" Patricia (pushing Patricia down).

```
A        |  B         | C                         |  D
First    |  Year      | City                      | 
---------------------------------------------------------
Peter    |  1990      | New York
Steven   |  1980      | Boston
Patricia
```

What is the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

you either need to introduce a system of IDs or have it sorted as it comes so every new entry will be always placed at the bottom. this way you won't disrupt the non-existent (manual) link.

Comment: Thanks! Adding IDs is fine but with which formulas (query, importrange, filter etc.) would work to prevent data is mixed up as shown above?

Only adding things at the bottom won't work unfortunately.

Comment: For example in table A, Peter ID is 14. In table B, Peter's ID should be 14 too. I'm not to good with GS formula but with app Script, easy to do.
You should think like DB : Go in the Table B, find the row where the ID 14 is and then add something to the column D